# Preventing from manipulation of disabled fields using developer tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, validation, user-interface

ASP.NET MVC and Angular based enterprise web application is hosted for external users access. We encountered a scenario like an user can manipulate the values shown in the disabled fields and submit so using the browser developer tool. e.g. (1) Input field of Vehicle Name, description etc. is disabled in the edit mode, but user can set the read-only field property to editable using dev tool and manipulate the actual value to something else.

similarly, e.g. (2) Customer details are fetched by ID from Cust db and shown on the screen. The customer details are expected to be saved in another db with a few more inputted details, but user edits the read-only customer fields using dev tool and submits.

As a solution, introducing a server side validation between retrieved and sent back values on every submission does not seem to be a right approach.

So, how to protect the read-only or static values from manipulating with browser or other dev tools?

Answer (score 4):

> As a solution, introducing a server side validation between retrieved and sent back values on every submission does not seem to be a right approach.

Contrary to what you appear to believe, that **is** the solution.

You cannot prevent the user from crafting their own HTTP request. You cannot prevent the user from hitting F12 and sending you garbage. It is up to you to validate whether the user is allowed to update the data they send you, and whether they are allowed to read the data they request.

Client-side validation is being nice for your users; server-side validation is an absolute necessity.